# Add an ID attribute to TD in a table using Jquery

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery

I want to add an ID attribute to a td elemnt in  a table genrated by sharepoint. I tried like this but it is not seeting the same.

Attached is the DOM object of my sharepoint form

[image]

```
$('ms-formtable tr').each(function (i, row) {var $row = $(row),$td=$row.find('td.ms-formlabel').attr('test');});
```

Comment: did you try .attr('id','test') or .prop('id','test') instead of .attr('test') ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using following codes:

Using JavaScript:

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll("td.ms-formbody");
for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    nodes[i].setAttribute("id", "test");
}
```

Using JQuery:

```
$('td.ms-formbody').prop('id','test');
```

Similary, you can add IDs for `td.ms-formlabel`.

Answer (score 3):

Plain JS: `document.querySelectorAll("td.ms-formbody").forEach((function(x){ x.setAttribute("id","test");}));`

jQuery: `$('td.ms-formbody').prop('id','test');`

Comment: Your jQuery solution works but Plain JS Solution is wrong. Your plain JS code will add id to just the first td because querySelector returns SINGLE element.

Comment: Ah, my misstake. Updated!

Answer (score 1):

Using plain JS you need to add loops.

```
    var allTds1 = document.querySelectorAll("td.ms-formlabel");
    allTds1.forEach(function(element) {
      element.setAttribute('id','test');
    });
    var allTds2 = document.querySelectorAll("td.ms-formbody");
    allTds2.forEach(function(element) {
      element.setAttribute('id','test');
    });
```

This will add id='test' to all td elements.